# Perguntas feitas com tonalidade diferente

Tags: debate, perguntas, duvida

Gostaria de entender(se houver algum motivo) por que as perguntas vêm com preenchimento de cor diferenciada das demais perguntas.
De inicio imaginei que essa mudança fosse para perguntas modificadas ou respondidas, mas não. Alguém sabe o porquê disso?

Exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]